# Can anyone help me to understand this output from tcpdump?

Tags: linux, networking, python, tcpdump

I wrote a code in python that extracts data from the FTX exchange using their API.
I am running the code in an AWS instance (free plan), located very closeby to the servers of the exchange.

#### Explanation of the code:

The code is essentially an infinite loop. At each step, it sends three gets request, elaborates the response, and then goes to the next step.
For the first few hundred iterations, the latency (defined below at the end of the post) for each block of three requests is of the order of 0.3seconds. After some time, it starts to grow up, reaching values from 2 to 5 seconds.
There are no ratelimits in the FTX API for `GET` requests, so I should not expect any limit from the server.

#### What I need:

I am trying to understand the origin of this extra-latency. To do so, I have monitored the https data traffic with `tcpdump` and I have modified the python script so that it stops as soon as it experiences a latency > 2 seconds. In this way, I can isolate the last packets in the `tcpdump` output and try to understand the origin of the delay.

However, I really don't know how to read the output (I uploaded it here https://pastebin.com/tAhcicPU).
Can anyone help me to understand the origin of the latency?
104.18.33.31.443 is the IP of FTX server
172.31.9.8 is the IP of the machine where my code runs

**Definition of latency used here**: I post the relevant part of the code where I compute the latency

```
latency=0
for pair in pairList:  # pairList  = ['BTC/USD','ETH/BTC','ETH/USD']
    api=requests.get(f'https://ftx.com/api/markets/{pair}/orderbook?depth={20}')
    latency+=api.elapsed.total_seconds()
return latency
```

So, the latency is the total sum of each latency returned by the requests.get for each request.

Comment: So your log only shows 5 seconds of execution time, and there's no latency there. I'm guessing there are other parts to your script, therefore, some other things to review are: is your script running out of memory? Is your script writing to disk, database, or a log in a performant way? Is your api using a persistent connection or is it keeping those connections open with each loop? There are many possible reasons, hopefully one of the above will help you.

Comment: @LuisAlbertoBarandiaran thank you. Isn't too long an execution time of 5seconds to get the packets? As I said, the latency that I am measuring doesn't count the time spent from the running of the code